# MomentJS return 0 when formatting time in seconds

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Also did a codepen so you can see console log: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LBKbmZ?editors=0012

So maybe i'm misunderstanding. I have this, `moment({ seconds: 0 }).set('hour', 7).seconds()`.

I create a `moment()` object. I set the `seconds` to 0. https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/object/.

I then do `set('hour', 7)` to set 7 hours. https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/set/.

I then do `seconds()` to convert the final value to into seconds. https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/seconds/.

Based on the docs this should work? I set the seconds to 0, I add 7 hours, i then convert the final time back to seconds. But I'm getting 0 back?

Am I using momentjs wrong or misunderstanding time?

Thank you

Comment: I dunno momentjs but as you can read in the link you posted, use `asSeconds()` to get the duration in seconds. `seconds()` merely returns the amount of seconds in the minute. `If you want the length of the duration in seconds, use moment.duration().asSeconds() instead.`

Comment: why not do `moment().add()` if your intent is to add 7 hours instead of the set()

Comment: @Xixis I don't want to worry about adding/subtracting time or anything. There's a timepicker. A user selects `9AM`. I just want to set the hour to 9 and convert to seconds. Adding/subtractings hours or minutes and stuff sounds messy. I could be wrong :)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

So the two suggested answers were helpful but I did a few things different and didn't use the `duration` method.

**Issue**: With a time picker which returns an object of `{hour: 3}` or `{minute: 3}` depending on what the user selected. Return that value in seconds. That way, internally, i'm always working with seconds and it's just easier.

Now if I use the above methods of `duration`, I convert the first user input into seconds, I save that, the user then makes a change in minutes, I can add that to the initial value i have saved, what if the user does a lower time? I need to do some logic to figure out if I need to do add or subtraction.

What I want is, a simple; I accept a time of hour or minutes. And I get that time in seconds from the start of the day. This is what I have:

```
let t = moment({ hour: 0, minute: 0, seconds: 0 }).add(savedTime, 'seconds');

t.set({ [hourOrMinute]: userinputTime }).diff(moment().startOf('day'), 'seconds')
```

So I set the initial time to 0. I then add the current saved time in seconds to that. I then set the time from what i previously had. I then do a diff, from the start of the day, to current time inputted and return in seconds.

Hopefully not too much text and it helps someone.

Comment: Not too much text, yet this one should not be the accepted answer. Even if this is the solution you are using in your code in the end it does not answer the/your initial question of why `seconds()` did not return the duration you expected it to. Else everyone would/could just close the question with their appropriate productive code snipped.

Answer (score 3):

For an instance of `moment`, the `seconds()` method gets you the "seconds" part of a date and time. That value will be between 0 and 59. The documentation for the `seconds()` method you are referring to belongs to a `duration` instance, which has a different implementation for this method.

It looks like you are trying to get the number of seconds since a certain starting point. You can create a `duration` instance and call its `seconds()` method:

```
moment.duration({hours: 7}).asSeconds();
```

The `moment` instance itself also offers the `unix()` method, which gets you the number of seconds elapsed since the UNIX epoch (Thursday, 1 January 1970 UTC).

Comment: But I can't use the `duration` method on a moment function. I want to set the initial seconds value. Suedo code kind of, so i'm aiming for this `moment({ seconds: previousInputInSeconds }).set(hour, userSelected9AM).asSeconds() // convert to seconds so i can set the previousInputInSeconds again`

Comment: You could calculate the difference between two moments using [diff](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/diffing/). That gets you a `duration`.

Answer (score 2):

As it states in the document you linked `asSeconds()` returns a duration whereas `seconds()` returns a timestamp.

So just try this one instead:
`console.log(moment.duration({hours: 70}).asSeconds(), '<<<----');`